# Stone space of finite Boolean algebras

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is the Stone space of **every** finite Boolean algebra a finite discrete space (for every finite Boolean algebra is complete, atomic, and isomorphic to the power set of its atoms; and finite discrete spaces are zero-dimensional, compact, and Hausdorff)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stone space of a finite Boolean algebra is clearly finite. But every finite Hausdorff space is discrete, hence yes: the Stone space of any finite Boolean algebra must be discrete. Even more is true: the category of finite Stone spaces is isomorphic to the category of finite sets, and there is an (anti-)equivalence between the category of finite sets and the category of finite Boolean algebras (see Johnstone's monograph).